# Twitter Bootstrap Fluid Grid system nesting not aligning with previous rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout, nested, grid-layout

I'm creating a form that uses [Twitter Bootstrap's Fluid Grid system](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem). A picture is worth a thousand words!

[image]

In the 3rd row (**Paciente**) there's some nesting going on. As you can see this nesting is causing a different alignment in the 2 column if compared to the first two rows. If you look at the orange line you can spot that...

I've set up a demo at JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/ayazul/1 using the latest Bootstrap version 2.2.2.

Debugging with Firebug I see a `left-margin` of `30px` in `<div class="span3">` in the 2nd row/2nd column. If I manually change that value to `20px` than the columns align correctly.

Why the first two rows have a different margin-left?

---

With the help of [Sherbrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14668657/114029), here's the final outcome the way I want it to be: http://jsbin.com/ayazul/29/ (the 2nd column is aligned in all three rows)

Comment: Try looking at the markup by using your browser's dev tools, it should show you where the extra padding/margin/etc.. is, if any.

Comment: Sure I did that... it's Bootstrap's calculations that are adding that different margin-left when using Fluid nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you keep the same structure `span6 > span6` on both rows instead of `span3` on the top row and `span6 > span6` on the second ?

Check the updated JSBin http://jsbin.com/ayazul/28/

This definitely adds extra markup, but it assures you the same appearance.

The "why" is quite simple : the margin (gutter) of the fluid columns is based on the parent total width. If the parent is in fact a `.span6` (50%) of the window width, it will have a lesser value than a column whose parent is at full window width. In other words, nested fluid spans diminishes the column real pixel width - for the fluid grid only.

Comment: Really nice Sherbrow! :) You explained it all! Having to add that extra markup is not a problem... it's a feature. hehehe

Answer (score 3):

Your markup is more complicated than it should be. You have way too many `.row-fluids` and `.span$` classes than needed. Why not something as simple as this?

http://jsbin.com/ayazul/6/

Comment: You provided a nice and valid alternative without the need of fluid nesting. Thanks istos!